# How to set elements in java long array in JNI?

Tags: java, android, arrays, java-native-interface

I'm trying to create a long array in JNI, basically some rectangle coordinates. I'm trying to store this in a long array that is already created in the Java class. Here is my Java code creating that array:

```
private long[] faceArray = new long[10];
```

Here is my JNI code to create and replace the `faceArray`:

```
void CreateJavaLongArray(JNIEnv *env, jlongArray& jLongArray, jobject thiz,
                         std::multiset<dlib::rectangle> mset) {
    jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(thiz);
    jfieldID jLongArrayId = env->GetFieldID(cls, "faceArray", "[J");
    jLongArray = (jlongArray) env->GetObjectField(thiz, jLongArrayId);
    jlong* body = env->GetLongArrayElements(jLongArray, 0);
    env->ReleaseLongArrayElements(jLongArray, body, JNI_ABORT);
    jLongArray = env->NewLongArray(mset.size() * 4);
    if (mset.empty()) {
        ALOGE("No unknown face found...");
        return;
    }
    int i = 0;
    ALOGI("Size of the rect set is: %d", mset.size());
    const int size = mset.size() * 4;
    long long arr[size];
    for (auto rect : mset) {
        arr[i++] = (long long)rect.left();
        arr[i++] = (long long)rect.top();
        arr[i++] = (long long)rect.right();
        arr[i++] = (long long)rect.bottom();
    }
    env->SetLongArrayRegion(jLongArray, 0, mset.size() * 4, arr);
}
```

But when I run the code I find that the array on the Java side has not changed. The size is still 10. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's not clear exactly how you call this `CreateJavaLongArray` function. In any case, you can't resize a Java array. So you'll either have to return a new array, or use a container class that can change in size dynamically (e.g. `ArrayList`).

Comment: Thankyou for pointing that out.

Comment: Take a look here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-no-045/ - it is 2D sample, but you can easily change it to 1D. Take a look here as well: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-014/